# Fortify Unreleased DB connection when using Factory pattern

Tags: java, fortify

We are facing a strange issue reported by fortify.
We are using afactory helper class to manage creation of DB connections .
Our helper class expost a getConnection method which is returning a connection object.this object will be released later by the caller of the method.
But fortify seems expecting the connection to be released within the getConnection method!!
Any advice please about this behaviour?

Comment: fortify is just giving you hints. carefully review the issue and if you are sure that connection has been released with try finally in every usecase then you are good.

Comment: Does it also flag this in the location where you use the connection if it goes unclosed? If yes, I say audit the factory method vulnerability as not an issue or suppress it and rely on it being flagged elsewhere.